# Как реализовать динамическую загрузку библиотек на сервер?

Tags: java, плагин

Здравствуйте. Есть `Java/Jsp` приложение с использованием `Spring`. Как реализовать возможность подгружать динамически `.jar` файлы. Приложение должно впоследствии использовать эту программу и показывать пользователю имеющиеся плагины. Также этот `.jar` файл использует классы и библиотеки в подгружаемом приложении.

Идея состоит в том, что программист делает дополнения (плагины), которые генерируют различные отчеты, и при помощи простого интерфейса загрузки, админ загружает `.jar` файл на сервер. Пользователь выбирает нужный ему отчет, который генерирует один из загруженных плагинов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример: [java-tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html)

Comment: Спасибо. А подскажите, конфликтов не будет, если классы jar-файла попытаются использовать методы и библиотеки использующего приложения?

Comment: проблемы будут только в том случае если оно не найдет каких-то классов, на сервере, которые используются в загруженном .jar файле. 

я думаю для того чтоб избежать ошибок ClassNotFoundException вам надо будет в classloader добавить сканирование всех классов которые запакованы в .jar и обрабатывать ошибки их загрузки. упало = невалидный плагин